# Complex quadratic equation always comes out as wrong

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

For some reason I always get the wrong answer and I don't understand why:

$$4z^2-12z+19=0$$

I got  $z= \frac{12 \pm \sqrt{260}i}{8}  $ and the answer is supposed to be $z=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{10}i}{2} $ where is my mistake?

Comment: They are the same thing, only a factor of $4$ was cancelled.

Comment: Note that $ \sqrt{260} $ (is that is what you meant) is typeset as `\sqrt{260}` .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your mistake is that the discriminant should be $12^2 - 4\times 4\times 19 = -160$, not $-260$, and then dividing top and bottom by $4$ gives the correct answer.

Comment: In applying the quadratic formula … it might help to divide all coefficients by the original *a* of 4 so that the *a* drops out or the adjusted *a=1* and the adjusted *b=-3* and adjusted *c=19/4* ... although it's best to keep it as simple as possible in order to minimize the likelihood of adding a mistake caused by extra cleverness … it's useful to understand the root cause of the error, eg b^2=44? rather 144 which lead to the -260 … in order to eliminate the likely missteps in one's problem-solving process.

Answer (score 6):

When the $x$ coefficient is even, say $ax^2+2bx+c=0,$ there is an equivalent version of the quadratic equation which automatically cancels that extra factor of $4.$

Instead of the usual discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ with this setup one calculates what might be called the "other" discriminant (for want of a better word) $E=b^2-ac$ as the thing under the radical. As usual if that's negative the complex number $i$ is used when square root of discriminant is taken.

Then the roots are $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{E}}{a}.$$

For the re-written example you have: $4z^2-2(-6)z+19=0,$ we get $E=(-6)^2-4\cdot 19=36-4\cdot 19=36-76=-40.$ Then roots are $(6 \pm \sqrt{-40})/12.$ This simplifies again in this case.

Comment: When you write "$ax^2+2bx+c=0$" and "$D=b^2-4ac$", those are two different $b$s. You should pick another letter for the first one.

Comment: @A.Howells That is clear from my explanation, and is why $E$ was used for $b^2-ac$ instead of the traditional $D$ for the discriminant (when no built-in multiplier of $2$ before $x$-coefficient.

Comment: @coffeemath It's not clear. The traditional discriminant would be $D = (2b)^2 - 4ac$.

Comment: @JiK And that, divided by $4,$ is $b^2-ac.$

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, but this answer claims that  $D = b^2 - 4ac$, which is wrong. The coefficient of the first degree term is $2b$ here, not $b$.

Comment: No, this answer claims that (more accurately, *defines*) $E=b^2-ac.$ Read it more closely. I made it clear that $D$ was the "usual" discriminant, and that $E$ was for the case of $x$ coefficient $2b$ instead of usual $b.$